# Using VTK in console application (visual studio) - access violation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, console-application, access-violation, vtk

I'm trying to implemente some functions of the VTK framework into my application. Compiling the code doesn't bring up any errors, but my app suffers from some "random" access violations.

You could reproduce this error with this example code from.

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/ReadSTL

**What works:**

Configuring the example project with cmake, compile, run application. No problem at all

**What doens't work:**

Start a new empty console application, configure all additional include directorys, VTK-lib files, VTK-dll files (I just copied this part of the configuration from the example project). Compiling works flawless without any erros. But at runtime I get an access violation thrown at this line of code:

```
mapper->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
```

Both projects are compile for a x64 target. Has anyone an idea what could cause this strange behavior?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I am posting this as an answer.

I personally never compiled a project in VTK without CMake, but for those who wish to persue this dark path, there is online documentation. You might consider looking into:

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Factories_now_require_defines